# IE8 says prototype's Form class is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, prototypejs

I'm doing an observer with

```
new Form.Observer('id', freq, etc...)
```

and my doctype is

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
...
```

and the error is 
'Form' is undefined

using prototype 1.6.0.3 in IE8
Works in chrome, safari, FF, etc

Comment: It's got to be a problem with the `script` tag. Have you checked for errors in the F12 Developer Tool's console? (And if not, why not? ;-) )

Comment: F12 is where I saw what the error was. o.o

Comment: but it might be related to jquery().has()? I have no idea.. IE is giving me an anuerism.

Comment: @TheLindyHop is it jQuery or Prototype? Or both, in which case are you using [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)?

Comment: It's prototype, and we are using noConflict with jQuery. I have no idea about this anymore.. the error just kind of went away after a while >_<

Answer (score 0):

In some cases this error seems to be solved by replacing

```
type="text/javascript"
```

with

```
type="application/javascript"
```

In the  tag.